# How to find a shortcode for total amount on checkout page and mulitple it with flat rate for shipping in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have setup a wordpress theme for eCommerce. Now i want to multiple the total amount with 12% and get the shipping amount.
I have tried the procedd with qty and check it worked or not ? Its working with qty but i did not find the shortcode of total amount.
Any body can help ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should multiply with the `[cost]` with a 12%.
Problem resolved.[image]